# Can we use Hibernate EntityManager to return an Entity with any other attributes other than primarykey?

Tags: hibernate, orm

I want to use entityManager to get the object based on the unique code.
that is:

```
EntityManager em;

bizObj.setCustomer(em.getReference(Customer.class , customerId));  //This works

Can I do as follows: (Say customerCode is unique), I want to retrieve based on customercode


// Assume code is unique

entity.setCustomer(em.getReference(Customer.class , customerCode);  //This throws exception
```

**Exception;**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class xx.core.model.Business. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getReference(SessionImpl.java:3405)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.getReference(AbstractEntityManager.java:502)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using getReference(), if you read the oracle docs they clearly mention it should be primary key
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

if you have a unique identified you can use TypedQuery.getSingleResult()